# tsc won't let me compile using the await keyword, even thought the function I'm using is async

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

When I try to compile:

```
const result = await asyncFunction();
```

I get the "'await' expression is only allowed with an async function" error, even though the function I'm using is using the async keyword. I keep getting this error while using multiple different async functions that are working for others, so I know it is something that I am doing wrong.

I'm using typescript 3.2.2, and compiling to node 10.15.0, but have also tried compiling to 11.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

> The `await` operator is used to wait for a `Promise`. It can only be used inside an `async function`.

This code is valid:

```
async function test() {
  const result = await asyncFunction();
}
```